# relative elements are on top of table header ngx-virtual-scroll

Tags: html, css, angular, html-table

I am having an issue with position relative `td` items to be underneath the `theader`

**component.html**

```
<virtual-scroller #scroll [items]="items">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead #header>
      <th>title</th>
      <th>value1</th>
      <th>value2</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody #container>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of scroll?.viewPortItems">
        <td>{{item.title}}</td>
        <td>{{item.value}}</td>
        <td>{{item.value2}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</virtual-scroller>
```

**component.css**

```
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

virtual-scroller {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

table {
  overflow: hidden;
}

thead {
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

th {
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
}

td {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  position: relative
}
```

**component.ts**

```
// ...
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  items = new Array(100).fill({title: 'test', value: 0, value2: 0});

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.items);
  }
}
```

basically what is happening is I am setting the `td` to have a position of relative because i want to position an element inside the td (not shown) with absolute positioning but as soon as i set the `position: relative` the `td` scroll over the `thead` instead of under it..

I have created a stackblitz of this isssue

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-z9qtdb

My desired result is to be able to set the `td` as position relative and keep the fixed header on top of the `td` items - if you remove `position: relative` from the `td` it works as expected

Is there any way to achieve this??

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by adding this to the `thead`

```
thead {
  // ...
  position: relative; // make sure this stays
  display: table-caption;
}
```

This does essentially 'break' the table header but in my case it works fine - would be better if there was a better solution